# Change byte array to integer in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a byte array need to convert to integer, and this array only have one value. I tried Bitconverter, convert.ToInt32 both are not working for me. my code as follows:

```
Dim a As new Byte() ={&H1C} ' the value range is {&H01} to {&HFF}
Dim key As integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(a,1)
```

I need the result with key = 28, which convert function I should use?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`BitConverter.ToInt32` needs 4 bytes to work with, so you just need to put your one byte value into a 4 byte array.  Allowing for the endianness, something like this:

```
Dim a() As Byte = { &H1C }
Dim b(3) As Byte
If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
    b(0) = a(0)
Else
    b(3) = a(0)
End If
Dim key As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0)
```

Comment: Hi@Mark, thanks for your answer, I tested it, and kind like not working for me, finally, I use CInt() function to do this part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not converting an array of values, but rather a single array element.

That said, there is no need to call a conversion function to convert a single `Byte` to an `Integer`.  Just assign the value.

```
Dim key As Integer = a(0)
```

Comment: Haha, simpler is better... now I feel like a dummy for my answer!

Comment: @mark, honestly this whole question should be deleted.  I only posted this after reading the OP's comment to your answer and wanted see if I could trigger some brain cell's.